# Ubuntu install multiple Cuda toolkit versions and their patches

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I can install multiple versions of Cuda toolkit using

```
sudo sh cuda-9.x.run --silent --toolkit --toolkitpath=/usr/local/cuda-9.x
```

Where x = 0, 1, 2

But how can I install patches for each of the cuda toolkit installs, eg the patch 1 for 9.0 using the following fails:

```
sudo sh cuda_9.0.176.1_linux.run --silent --toolkit --toolkitpath=/usr/local/cuda-9.0

Unknown option: toolkit
Unknown option: toolkitpath
```

I couldnt see how to do this in the install guide: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.1/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
./cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run --silent --toolkit --toolkitpath=/tmp
./cuda_9.0.176.1_linux.run --silent --accept-eula --installdir=/tmp
```